# How to implement Secondary Search on Kendo Grid column

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui, grid

I am new to Kendo UI widgets and have a question regarding sorting.
I have a Kendo grid with default sorting assigned to one column on databound.
When the user sorts another column, the default sorting would go and the grid would get sorted based on the user selected column.

My requirement is, when the user selects a different column to sort, the default column should also get sorted i.e., secondary sort should be applied on the default column.

Below are the code snippets,

Sorting is applied on the datasource,

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DeviceDetails_VM>()
            .Name("griddeviceDetail")
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "auto; " })
            .Events(e =>e.Edit("OnColumnEdit").ColumnReorder("onColumnReorder").ColumnResize("onColumnResize").DataBinding("onDataBinding").DataBound("onDataBound"))
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .ColumnMenu(s => { s.Filterable(true); s.Sortable(true); })
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(x => x.PK_AllAssetID);
}.Sortable()
.DataSource(datasource => dataSource
.Ajax()
.Sort(x => x.Add(PK_AllAssetID).Order(Descending))
.PageSize(25))
```

There are huge number of columns in the grid. I did not add them to aid readability.

Where should I apply secondary sort? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on Telerik's demo pages: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/sorting. And that's the documentation for this feature: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/GridBuilder#methods-Sortable(System.Action%3CKendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridSortSettingsBuilder%3CT%3E%3E)

This allows the user to sort by multiple columns by himself.